# Can't make https request from inside docker container, but it works fine on the host machine

Tags: networking, proxy, ssl, docker, https

In my application I need to make request from Docker container to my company's internal JIRA instance, but the requests always time out. I can make https requests to other sites from inside the container, and I can also make https requests to the JIRA instance from the host machine.

I've tried passing ports: "443:443" to the container in which I need to make the request, but it didn't help.

When i curl the URL on the host machine, beginning of the output is that:

```
curl -v [URL]
* About to connect() to proxy [proxy address] port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying [proxy address]...
* Connected to [proxy address] ([proxy address]) port 8080 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to [URL]:443
> CONNECT [URL]:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: [URL]:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
< Proxy-Agent: Fortinet-Proxy/1.0
<
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
[rest of the successful response]
```

After that I set http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables in the container to the proxy address from the fragment above. After trying to curl the same URL from the container, I had this output:

```
*   Trying [proxy address]...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to (nil) ([proxy address]) port 8080 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Operation timed out after 300000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 300000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

Another idea I've had, I thought that I could make the requests using host machine's ip in the docker network as proxy, but I couldn't get it to work. Is it even possible?

EDIT: My bad for not updating when I found the solution. In my case it had something to do with port forwarding. A more experienced engineer from my company helped me by giving a command that made it work:

```
iptables -l FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

I did not investigate further what each of the flags did and what was the root cause, as I was pretty fed up with all that stuff. This worked until rebooting the host machine, but there is a way to make iptables changes permanent.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: @alex88 Yeah I did, my bad for not updating the post, sorry! Going to put the information there now

Comment: Thanks, I've actually found my issue too, it was the MTU setting in the calico configuration